# I cannot parse an object from string to object in javascript

Tags: javascript, json, string, parsing, d3.js

I am trying to parse the string d to an object.
First of all, I have already looked up through the Internet trying to find a solution, but all I found is related to JSON.stringify(d), which is deprecated; and to JSON.parse(d), which gives me the error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o(anonymous function) @
>   map.js:286(anonymous function) @ d3.v3.min.js:1

The code is the following: (the commented lines are some of my different trials)

```
apartmentinfo.append('p')
    .append('a')
    .attr('class', 'descriptionbutton buttonleft')
    .on('click', function () {
    //javascript convert string into object
    //var json = JSON.stringify(d);
    //var descrip = eval('(' + d + ')');
    //var apart = JSON.parse(d);
    changeApartmentInfo(d);
    viewSingleApartment();
 })
 .text("Description");
```

And whenever I use console.log(d) to print d, this appears in the console:

```
Object{ id: "Whatever", name: "Whatever", description: "Whatever", piso_url: "Whatever", piso_imagen: "Whatever"… (HERE I HAVE AN INFO ICON THAT SAYS: Object state below is captured after first expansion)
description: "Whatever"
host_id: "Whatever"
host_name: "Whatever"
id: "Whatever"
latitude: "Whatever"
licencia: "Whatever"
longitude: "Whatever"
name: "Whatever"
piso_imagen: "Whatever"
piso_url: "Whatever"
price: "Whatever"
red: "Whatever"
room_type: "Whatever"}
```

I don't know what else to try, any idea?

Thank you very much

Comment: Show us this object. You can also use some online JSON validators to check if this string is correct

Comment: I have edited the comment with the object

Comment: Are there `{` and `}` in `d`?  Also, don't `...` the file.  The beginning and end could be what are breaking it.

Comment: When was `JSON.stringify()` deprecated?

Answer (score 1):

In JSON, dictionary keys must be stings, like:

```
'{"id": "Whatever", "name": "Whatever", "description": "Whatever"}'
```